# Behavior of a for loop with HTTP request

Tags: node.js

Hello Dears Programmer

I'm facing a strange behavior, maybe that's just a problem of logic, but I want to make it right and sure .

I have a list of dynamics HTTP urls that I iterate . But I want the request to be sent on a precise time ( Each 3200 ms for example here ) for this, I made a while that wait until the diffence between the very first call of Date.now() and the latest reach my desired amount .

```
  for(let j=0;j<5;j++){

      let currentTime = Date.now()

      //console.log("ELAPSED TIME",currentTime-start)

      let againstTime = currentTime-start
      let against = againstTime < 3200
      //console.log(againstTime)


      while(against){ 
        againstTime = Date.now() - start
        against = againstTime < 3200
        console.log(againstTime)

      }

      console.log("Done")


      start = Date.now()

      https.get("SomeURL", (res)=>{
        //console.log("SINGLE "+SingleProduct+" Sended ",Date.now()-start)

        var innerChunk
        res.on("data", function (data){
          innerChunk += data
        }) 

        res.on("end", function(){
          /* Do Some Logic */
        }
    }
```

But actually what I have now ( for this case (5 requests) )

While is executed 5 times .

Whichever number of request, Code after the while is reached only after the while is executed the number of time the loop iterate .

Request are sended in a bunch .

What do I miss in the NodeJs Paradigm regarding while loop ?

Comment: So basically you want to request every 3200ms right ?

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend you use an asynchronous call instead of a while loop that binds up the main thread. Using a while loop as a timer is bad practice, inaccurate, and prone to breaking.

The easiest option would be to use [`setInterval`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args) like so:

```js
let i = 0;
let inter = setInterval(function(){
    console.log("Send your request here");
    if (++i >= 5) {
        clearInterval(inter);
        console.log("Done!");
    }
}, 3200);
```

If you simply want to ping back and forth between a server and a client a number of times, I would recommend you take a look at using the [WebSockets API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) instead of making discrete web requests. WebSockets allow you to open a persistent connection and send data back and forth without the overhead of making multiple XHRs. This approach would likely require changes to the server you're sending requests to, but if you control it, this is worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` instead of `for` loop, but `precise time` is not really possible as timer will just make sure that request will execute at minimum after scheduled time https://nodejs.org/uk/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#timers

```
const betweenRequests = 3200
const makeRequest = () => {
    console.log("yay")
}

makeRequest() // execute one now and others starting after 'betweenRequests'
let noRequests = 4
const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  --noRequests
  makeRequest()
  if (noRequests < 1) clearInterval(intervalId)
}, betweenRequests)
```